# Cannot access data with LinkedList

Tags: java

I have classes named Item, Store, Customer and Online(for online customer).

**Item**

```
public class Item{
   public Item(String code, String name){
      this.code = code;
      this.name = name;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString(){
      return name + " : " + code;
}
```

**Store**

```
 public class Store{
        private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
        public Store(String name, String number){
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
        }
       public void addItem(String code, String name){
          items.add(new Item(this, code, name);
       }
       @Override
       public String toString() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (Item item : items) {
            sb.append(item.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
       }
       return sb.toString();
    }

    public void viewStore(){
        System.out.println(name + " " + number);
    }
}
```

**Customer**

```
 import java.util.LinkedList;

class Customer {
    private LinkedList<Store> stores = new LinkedList<Store>();

    public Customer() {
        stores.add(new Store("Game", "1"));
        stores.add(new Store("Grocery", "2"));

        stores.get(0).addItem("001A", "GTA");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001B", "GOD OF WARS");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001C", "THE LAST OF US");

        stores.get(1).addItem("002A", "Sandwich");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002B", "Cup Noodle");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002C", "Ice Cream");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Customer().viewStore();
        System.out.println();
        new Customer().viewItem();
    }

    public void viewStore(){
        for(Store store: stores)
            store.viewStore();
    }

    public void viewItem(){
        for(Store store: stores)
            System.out.println(store);
    }
}
```

**Online**

```
import java.util.*;
class Online {
    private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
    private String name;
    private String number;
    public Online(String name, String number){
      this.name=name;
      this.number = number;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
       new Online("John", "123").viewItem();
    }


    private void viewItem(){
       for(Item item: items)
           System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

I try to access items data under 'Online' class but failing constantly;

```
for(Item item: items)
    System.out.println(item)
```

I though the output would be like this

```
   GTA : 001A
   GOD OF WARS : 001B
   THE LAST OF US: 001C

   Sandwich: 002A
   Cup Noodle: 002B
   Ice Cream: 002C
```

But instead it print out NOTHING.

Can someone explain to me? I think I am wrong with adding or accessing data.

Also, for testing purposes. Can you tell me how can I check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your list in `Online` does not contain anything. Why do you expect otherwise?

Comment: But I added in the Customer.

Comment: and when is customer called in your Online class?

Comment: Variables in separate objects are not related to each other regardless of matching name and type. An `Online` object has its own `items`, which is different from the `items` lists in `Customer` objects (note that in case of multiple `Customer` objects, they have separate lists on their own, unless you make it `static` which you should not do, real-life customers prefer having their own cart/basket too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a public accessor/getter of `items` in the class, `Store` to access it in the class, `Customer`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Item {
    private String code, name;

    public Item(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " : " + code;
    }
}

class Store {
    private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
    private String name, number;

    public Store(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void addItem(String code, String name) {
        items.add(new Item(code, name));
    }

    public LinkedList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Item item : items) {
            sb.append(item.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void viewStore() {
        System.out.println(name + " " + number);
    }
}

class Customer {
    private LinkedList<Store> stores = new LinkedList<Store>();

    public Customer() {
        stores.add(new Store("Game", "1"));
        stores.add(new Store("Grocery", "2"));

        stores.get(0).addItem("001A", "GTA");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001B", "GOD OF WARS");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001C", "THE LAST OF US");

        stores.get(1).addItem("002A", "Sandwich");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002B", "Cup Noodle");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002C", "Ice Cream");
    }

    public void viewStore() {
        for (Store store : stores)
            store.viewStore();
    }

    public void viewItem() {
        for (Store store : stores) {
            for (Item item : store.getItems()) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Online {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.viewStore();
        System.out.println();
        customer.viewItem();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Game 1
Grocery 2

GTA : 001A
GOD OF WARS : 001B
THE LAST OF US : 001C
Sandwich : 002A
Cup Noodle : 002B
Ice Cream : 002C
```